# Como redireccionar con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo en un link que me envia a /stock/products/ con el filtro de la categoría aplicado.

```
<a href="/stock/products/?categoryId=<?php echo $categoryId; ?>" class="ViewProducts" id="view" ><?php echo __("Ver productos"); ?></a>
```

Y necesito saber como realizar lo siguiente:

- Al hacer click en "Ver productos" me redirecciona a la pagina de productos pero, como hacer para que me muestre solo los productos de la categoria donde realice el click? como realizar esa function? (Ver imagen categorias)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por ejemplo, supongamos que con tu código se genera un link:

```
<a href="/stock/products/?categoryId=3">Telefonos</a>
```

este se envía a una pagina en php en donde se captura este valor mediante un metodo get

`$variable = $_GET['categoryId'];`

`$consulta = "SELECT id_item, nom_item, valor_item FROM items, categorias WHERE items.id_categoria=categorias.id and categorias.id='".$variable."'";`

y como te decía, después mostrar esos datos

```
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    //se imprime el resultado
    echo 
        '
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>'.$fila['id_item'].'</td>
                <td>'.$fila['nom_item'].'</td>
                <td>'.$fila['valor_item'].'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>';

}
```

me estoy saltando la conexion a la base de datos y otras cosas pero me imagino que se entiende la idea. Con esto estoy mostrando los datos de los items que corresponderían a la categoría de teléfonos.

Answer (score 0):

me imagino que esa información la tienes en una base de datos. Lo que te falta hacer es que la página donde estás enviando este `$categoryId` tome la variable y haga la consulta en la base de datos. Relacionas las tablas que pueden ser `items` y `categorias` y, por ejemplo, un `where id_categoria=$categoryId`.

Ya con eso vas a tener los items correspondientes a la categoría donde se hizo click y ya solo bastaría mostrarlos.

Comment: Si pudieras ayudarme con algun ejemplo de codigo, asi puedo entender mejor lo que me decis seria ideal :) te agradezco desde ya!